# Writer feature for interweaving the lines of multiple paragraphs. ie: musical or theatrical composition

Tags: libreoffice

Doable in Libre Office ? Doesn't need to take solid paragraphs and interweave them.Just need to set it up. So it does it as I type them.

The problem with manually doing it is every time I edit the text or change the font size it throws off the lines and I have to start all over again.

I'm sure there is lots of applications, all I can think of is in music where people are singing different words at the same time or a play-script where multiple conversations are going on at once or if you wanted to put non verbal cues underneath.

Example:

```
Paragraph 1 Line 1 
Paragraph 2 Line 1
Paragraph 1 Line 2
Paragraph 2 Line 2
```

Editing:

```
Paragraph 1 Line 1 if this line get too long it skips the next line and....
Paragraph 2 Line 1
....keeps going here. (Paragraph 1 Line 2)
Paragraph 2 Line 2
```

Comment: Cant do it with table formatting? Select rows you need to have similar formatting and set the formatting.

Comment: I'm not seeing any way to make tables do that. How can you "text-wrap" a row so that it continues on the next row? And it would actually need to skip a row and continue.

Comment: Looks like double spacing the main body(1st para) and for the 2nd layer/paragraph adding a frame on top of it that has a transparent background, is also double spaced and offset from the original is the best solution so far. I'll keep testing it.